# How do I show that these sums are the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, power-series

My textbook says that I should check that

$$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{\left( \lambda\mathtt{I} + \mathtt{J}_k \right)^i}{i!} $$

is in fact the same as the product of sums

$$ \left( \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{\left( \lambda\mathtt{I}\right)^i}{i!} \right) \cdot
\left( \sum_{j=0}^k\frac{\left( \mathtt{J}_k \right)^j}{j!} \right)$$

Where $ \mathtt{J}_k $ is all zero exept first super diagonal that has all ones.
But I can't figure out how to do it.

[edit]

To clarify: I'm working towards a definition of $f(\mathtt{A})$ where $f$ is a "nice" function, and $\mathtt{A}$ is an arbitrary square matrix.

The text basically goes like this.

$\mathtt{B} = f(\mathtt{A})$ defined as $b_{ij} = f(a_{ij})$ is a bad idea because 
$f(\mathtt{A})$ where $f(x) = x^2$ is generally not the same as $\mathtt{A}^2$ and so on.

BUT, we know that for numbers, $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} $ so lets try this for matrices.

Then it goes on to show that for diagonal matrices the power series gives the same result as if we would apply the function on the diagonal elements then its expanded to diagonalizable matrices. Then to Jordan blocks, and thats where these sums come in.

Comment: Binomial theorem

Comment: @i707107 Would you care to elaborate a bit, I'm kind of stuck here and I can't figure out how to proove this uing the binomial theorem, even if I see that it applies to the top sum.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$(1)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{X^k}{k!}=e^X$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;J_k^{n}=0\;,\;\;\;\text{where$\,n\,$ is the number of rows of the matrix}\;J_k$$

Comment: This sounds a bit circular. How do you prove that $e^{X+Y}=e^Xe^Y$ for commuting matrices $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: First of all, why would I, or the OP, *have* to show that? And second: it is shown exactly as with real or complex numbers.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that the purpose of an exercise like this is usually either (a) to verify independently that $e^{X+Y}=e^Xe^Y$ for commuting $X$ and $Y$, or (b) to illustrate a crucial step for proving the general equality. But of course you are right and you're answering the OPs question as it stands.

Comment: @DonAntonio Actually I should have been more clear about what the purpose is. The chapter I'm reading is working towards a definition of a function on a matrix. So $e^X$ is not really defined yet.